# Using linalg.block_diag for variable number of blocks

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, parameter-passing

So I have a code that generates various matrices. These matrices need to be stored in a block diagonal matrix. This should be fairly simply as I can use scipy's:

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag(*arrs)
```

However the problem I have is I don't know how many matrices will need to be stored like this. I want to keep things as simply as possible (naturally). I thought of doing something like:

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag( matrix_list[ii] for ii in  range(len(matrix_list)) )
```

But this doesn't work. I can think of a few other ways to do it... but they all become quite convoluted for something I feel should be much simpler.

Does anyone have an idea (or know) a simple way of carrying this out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are `a`, `arrs`, `matrix_list`? what isn't working? are you getting an error?

Comment: *arrs is just terminlogy scipy use in their help.

a is actually a mistake, meant to type matrix_list (I'll go edit the post to correct this).

matrix_list is just a list where the matrices are stored

Comment: And what do you get when you do `scipy.linalg.block_diag(*matrix_list)`?

Comment: `ValueError: Arguments in the following positions have dimension greater than 2: [0]`


It's happy enough if I state the matrices that are stored in the matrix list. So for example, let's say I have:
`a`, `b`, `c` -> some matrices
`matrix_list = [a, b, c]`

It's happy with: `scipy.linalg.block_diag(a, b, c)` but it's not happy with `scipy.linalg.block_diag(matrix_list)` which is frustrating as the amount of matrices in `matrix_list` may vary depending on initial conditions.

Comment: try again, this time with the `*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag( matrix_list[ii] for ii in  range(len(matrix_list)) )
```

you're passing a generator expression to `block_diag`, which is not the way to use it.

Instead, use the `*` opertor, for expanding the argument list in the function call, like:

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag(*matrix_list)
```

Comment: Oh, that's why they had a * I thought it was just formatting (I feel silly now!). That's brilliant, exactly what I needed, thank you very much!